# $\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{3}{n}\right)^\frac{n}{2}$

Tags: calculus, logarithms

I am trying to resolve this to number $e$. However, I would like to do it in the simplest form. just a note I already tried wolfram but I would like someone to give me a simpler solution.

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{3}{n}\right)^\frac{n}{2}$$

Thanks,

Comment: I think it is $e^{3 \over 2}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An answer that only uses the definition of $e$: 
$$\left(1 + \frac{3}{n}\right)^{n/2} = \left(1 + \frac{1}{n/3}\right)^{(n/3)*(3/2)} = \left[\left(1 + \frac{1}{n/3}\right)^{n/3}\right]^{3/2} \stackrel{(m = \frac{n}{3})}{=} \left[\left(1 + \frac{1}{m}\right)^{m}\right]^{3/2} \to e^{3/2}$$

Answer (score 5):

Hint:

$$\left(1+\frac3n\right)^{n/2}=\left[\left(1+\frac3n\right)^n\right]^{1/2}$$

Answer (score 3):

Use the fact that:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(1 + \frac kn\right)^n = e^k$$

So we have:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(1 + \frac 3n\right)^\frac n2 = e^{\frac 32}$$

Answer (score 0):

You can go this way

> $$ e^{n/2\ln(1+3/n)}=e^{n/2( 3/n-3^2/n^2+\dots )}\longrightarrow_{n\to \infty}\dots\,. $$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $$\lim_{n \to \infty} (1 + \frac{x}{n})^n = e^x$$

Answer (score 0):

Write it as $\lim_{n\to\infty}(1+\frac{3}{n})^{\frac{n}{2}}=lim_{n\to\infty}[(1+\frac{3}{n})^{\frac{n}{3}}]^{\frac{3}{2}}$